# Whether to create a new question in stackoverflow or edit my old one giving links to my code

Tags: discussion

I think this is the correct place for this question, if not if someone could point me in the right direction.

Here is a link to my original question
[Ruby substitute for goto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23202836/ruby-substitute-for-goto)

I wanted to clarify what I was trying to accomplish with this question and to do so I would like to show my code but it is 143 lines long and the rspec is another 83.

What would be the best way to do this? Post my code on github and edit my old post adding a link? Link to the code in a new post with a link to my old post? Create a new post with my code in it even though its so long?

Comment: **Always** post code in-line.  **Never** link to an external site except to supplement what's in the post (like to a live example / "fiddle" site).  [Have you read the bits about how to make a reduced test case](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Charles I'll just copy in the code but should I create a new post or just massively edit my old one?

Comment: you should edit the old one if the question hasn't changed. Please, make sure you make a reduced test case. It's likely that a large number of those 226 lines are irrelevant to your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Generally Speaking

Generally speaking, the proper thing to do if your question is essentially the same as the old one is to edit your old question to add your code. When people repost the same question chances are that someone is going to notice that it is the same question and they will flag the post as duplicate or vote to close it as duplicate. When the duplicate is from the same user as the user who posted the original question, downvotes are *sure* to accompany the flagging or vote to close.

In one case I've noticed a user who reposted their question but took care to delete the original one, perhaps thinking that their deed would go unnoticed. They did not realize that users with >= 10K of reputations can see deleted posts. These shenanigans earned them downvotes on the repost and votes for closure (because the post was suffering from issues quite independent from it being a repost).

The lesson here is don't repost unless you want a negative response.

#### Your Case

I notice that your question already has an accepted answer. And this answer is responding to what you've put in your question. It would be a cheap thing to do to the person who has already helped you and whose answer you've accepted if you changed your question in such a way that their answer looks like it is not actually answering your question, or that it is lazy answer.

Proceed with caution if you decide to edit the old one.

Comment: This answer could be pretty confusing for newbies. First you say "don't repost unless you want a negative response" and later "Proceed with caution if you decide to edit the old [question]." So the OP is damned if he do and damned if he don't? I would clarify that asking a new question is perfectly acceptable (and, in fact, encouraged) as long as it is substantially different from the first question.

Comment: I went with asking a new question as the answers given answered my question.  The question was just poorly asked and I should have been more specific with it.  Thanks

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot "So the OP is damned if he do and damned if he don't?" Yep. It is not rare that SO users that don't have much experience with the site indeed back themselves into a corner. In such cases, every option is likely to lead to a bad outcome.